# jqgrid column linq with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a class (Person) with 4 properties : Id, FirstName, LastName, Code.

I show a person list in a jqgrid. I'd like a link column with this format (the code has this format 2011.0001)

/Person/Detail/Code => /Person/Code/2011.0001

But I have this with the code below :
/Customer/Detail?Code=2

I tried this :

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Customer/Detail', idName: 'Code' }},
    { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', align: 'left' },
    { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', align: 'left' }                  
],
```

How can I correct this ?

Thanks,

Update1, Data format

```
[
{"Id":1,"FirstName":"AAAA","LastName":"AA","Code":"2011.0001"},
{"Id":3,"FirstName":"BBBB","LastName":"BB","Code":"2011.0003"}
]
```

Comment: Could you post the test data which you use to fill the grid? Are the values from the `Code` unique? Could be probably the column be used as the `id` for the grid rows?

Comment: See update1. Code is unique yes, there is an a technical id but I'd like the controller receive the code value.

Comment: If you need to have the URL in the form `/Person/Code/2011.0001` and not for example in the form `/Person?Code=2011.0001` having URL parameters you should use custom formatter. See my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) in the form

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<a href="/Person/Code/' + rowObject.Code + '">' + cellvalue + '</a>';
}
```

instead of [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter) 'showlink':

```
formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl:'/Customer/Detail', idName:'Code'}
```

You can easy receive `/Customer/Detail?Code=2011.0001` if you have unique data in the 'Code' column and if you would add `key: true` to the column definition. In the case the `Id` value from the JSON input will be ignored and the value from the 'Code' column will be used as the rowid. If you do need to have the `href` value in the form `/Customer/Detail/Code/2011.0001` or instead of `/Customer/Detail?Code=2011.0001` you will need use custom formatter as I described before.