# jqGrid formatoptions that include other name value of same colModel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is the colModel:

....

```
{ name: 'jobid', index:'jobid', formatter:'showlink', 
   formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'display.php', addParam:'&jobid=jobid&jobstack=jobstack'}
},
{ name: 'jobstack', index:'jobstack', editable: true },
```

....

as you can see, my intention is to create an external link that holds the get value of name and jobstack, and I just can't figure out how to get the values right.  I have check the documentation but i didn't find any.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to my that you should better use custom formetter instead of `'showlink'` formatter. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138750/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7294913/315935) or [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119297/showlink-custom-formatter-with-anchor-and-image-in-jqgrid/7120678#7120678) for details and for code examples. Alternatively you can use [unobtrusive style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for creating of external links. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528) for details.